# pfSense with a bridge as a LAN interface : traffic blocked between interfaces

Tags: bridge, pfsense

I have a pfSense 2.0-BETA3 box as a home router. The box has 3 wired ETH ports and a wireless interface. It is configured as follow :

- WAN : vr0
- LAN : BRIDGE0
- OPT1 : vr1
- OPT2 : vr2
- OPT3 : ath0 (wireless card)
- BRIDGE0 : OPT1, OPT2, OPT3

There is a PC connected directly behind OPT1, and a switch connected behind OPT2 with multiple computers behind it. pfSense handles the NAT to connect to the internet and DHCP to all hosts.

I have a rule to allow all traffic from LAN to any.

Connecting from any of the interfaces behind pfSense can connect to the net with no problem. But connections from a PC behind OPT1 to a PC behind OPT2 fail. Using Wireshark, I can see that SYN packet are sent, but no response is received (or ICMP echo request, with no echo response).

What more should I configure to allow traffic between the different interfaces of the bridge ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. After adding firewall rules from the bridge member interfaces to the bridge network it seems to work. Cheers
Cidi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.

After adding firewall rules from the bridge member interfaces to the bridge network it seems to work.

Cheers
Cidi

Comment: That's exactly right. Create a rule for each interface in the bridge, allowing traffic from any source to the bridge itself, and everything works just fine.